How to get socket Tx timestamps from python socket.sendmsg
While reading here, here and here I see that on Linux systems you can request timestamps from received and transmitted packets by setting socket options. I am currently able to use SO_TIMESTAMPNS and SO_TIMESTAMPING to get Rx timestamps with recvmsg. With sendmsg I don't know how to properly package the ancillary data for the control message and sendmsg doesn't even have a return that could hold the data I need.
This is how I'm getting the Rx timestamp.
import socket    

SO_TIMESTAMPING = 37
SOF_TIMESTAMPING = 127

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, SO_TIMESTAMPING, SOF_TIMESTAMPING)

server_sock.bind((_svr_ip, _svr_port))
server_sock.listen(_num_clients)
conn, client_addr = server_sock.accept()

msg, ancdata, flags, address = conn.recvmsg(64, 1024)

t_rx = ancdata[0][2]
t_rx_s = int.from_bytes(t_rec[0:7], byteorder="little")
t_rx_ns = int.from_bytes(t_rec[8:], byteorder="little")


Section 1.3.4 mentions enabling timestamps via control messages without having to use socket.setsockopt to reserve overhead. I believe that means you are adding the flag to the control message while calling sendmsg instead of using socket.setsockopt.

Can you elaborate? What socket type can I use to get the Tx timestamp?

To correct myself: The feature is about getting timestamp information, i.e. when data arrived at the system. It's only about receiving, not sending. Hence only recvmsg, not sendmsg.

the feature clearly states.
SO_TIMESTAMPING
Generates timestamps on reception, transmission or both. Supports multiple timestamp sources, including hardware. Supports generating timestamps for stream sockets.
and has these modifiers
SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE
SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE
SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE
SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE

I can also verify that the network adapter supported Rx and TX timestamps by using command "sudo ethtool -T IFNAME"

It's likely the python wrapper has not been implemented but it is definitely possible on any modern Linux system.

Strange. The sentence introducing the list where you cite from clearly states: "The interfaces for receiving network packages timestamps are:". Do you have C code using this feature with sendmsg?

I do not, but I'm thinking that one possible option is to use ctypes and implement this in C inside of the python code, or implement it in C outside of python and run it from python.

I actually though about your last comment before and was wondering if the TX timestamp was from the sender and was adding into the ancillary data, but I've also read that no data from sender is added "on the wire" during transport so that is unlikely unless it's sent and received from the same computer.
